# What function icons means in Qt creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, intellisense

I am using Qt creator.

When I want to call function of object, appears drop-down menu with list of possible functions. Each function have icon. (**Qt intellisense**)

Is there any place, where I can find definition of each icon?

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you explain more ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go:
http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-completing-code.html

The detail of each and every symbol.
Qt documentation just rocks ;)
Go crazy!

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly, what I was trying to find.